# Infinite Progress Bar android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a view which has as many progress bar I want. Fortunately, I searched in Android studio it doesn't have the below specified Views.

For Example, I Want to show 6 progress lines one after another. So there will be 6 progress lines which will be filled up with colors one after another.
It's like instagram that whenever we open the story it shows one story and many progress line.

[image: This image shows the progress line which I want]

Comment: which way the progress bar you showed is infinite?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes it's infinite. like if i say 10 progress than it should give me 10 progress bar. this happens in Instagram when we see the story of a person.

Comment: it has nothing related to *infinite*. Probably you don't know what *infinite* means?

Comment: you may want to use multiple progressbars in the row to achieve simillar effect

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i mean to say that infinitely it may changed. Ok then can you help me with a fixed number of progress line.?

Comment: review : https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper

Comment: Try placing multiple progressbars in a row in layout

Comment: check this library https://github.com/shts/StoriesProgressView